# jsonencode adding unwanted blackslash

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

Here is my code :

```
locals {
 meta = "{\"ABC\":${var.value1},\"XYZ\":${var.value2}}"
}
variable value1 {
   default = "google.com"
}
variable value2 {
   default = "yahoo.com"
}
```

**Output:**

> jsonencode(local.meta)
> "{"ABC":google.com,"XYZ":yahoo.com}"

I get unwanted backslashes in the output

**output must be the following:**

> {"ABC":"google.com","XYZ":"yahoo.com"}

Answer (score 1):

Your `local.meta` should be:

```
locals {
 meta = {ABC = var.value1, XYZ = var.value2}
}
```